# MySQL - can I limit the maximum time allowed for a query to run?

Tags: mysql, long-running-processes

I'm looking for a way to limit the max running time of a query on mysql server. I figured this could be done through the `my.cnf` configuration file, but couldn't find anything relevant in the docs. Anyone knows if this could be done? thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a maximum execution time for a mysql query ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415905/how-to-set-a-maximum-execution-time-for-a-mysql-query)

Comment: this points to a lock_wait_timeout, which is not what I need. I want an expiration timeout on the query, regardless if a lock was acquired or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Update

As of MySQL 5.7, you can include a [`MAX_EXECUTION_TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-execution-time) optimizer hint in your `SELECT` queries to instruct the server to terminate it after the specified time.

As far as I know, if you want to enforce a server-wide timeout, or if you care about queries besides `SELECT`s, the original answer is still your only option.

### Original answer

There is no way to specify a maximum run time when sending a query to the server to run.

However, it is not uncommon to have a cron job that runs every second on your database server, connecting and doing something like this:

1. SHOW PROCESSLIST
2. Find all connections with a query time larger than your maximum desired time
3. Run KILL [process id] for each of those processes

Comment: every second may be a bit of overkill depending on your situation. You should put some thought into the need to kill processes in order to keep your max_connections from being hit - all this depends on the load on your specific machine.

Comment: This is no longer true. Please see the posts about using `max_execution_time`.

Answer (score 15):

You could use a query as follows:

```
SELECT MAX_STATEMENT_TIME=1000 * FROM table;
```

UPDATE:
You should use **max_execution_time** instead.

```
SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000)*/ * FROM table;
```

MAX_STATEMENT_TIME was renamed to max_execution_time in MySQL 5.7.8. 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time

Comment: Try to improve your answer

Answer (score 5):

In the meantime the Twitter team released their changes to MySQL which implements this:

`- Reduce unnecessary work through improved server-side statement timeout support. This allows the server to proactively cancel queries that run longer than a millisecond-granularity timeout.`

See http://engineering.twitter.com/2012/04/mysql-at-twitter.html and https://github.com/twitter/mysql/wiki/Statement-Timeout

Answer (score 4):

http://mysqlserverteam.com/server-side-select-statement-timeouts/

Interesting upgrade. I will check it:

"MySQL 5.7.4 introduces the ability to set server side execution time limits, specified in milliseconds, for top level read-only SELECT statements".

```
SET GLOBAL MAX_STATEMENT_TIME=1000;
SET SESSION MAX_STATEMENT_TIME=2000;
SELECT MAX_STATEMENT_TIME=1000 * FROM table;
```