# How to set php max execution time in millisecond?

Tags: php

Is there any way to set php max execution time less than a second?

or

How can we handle it in code level like return a json message to show "Exceeded max allowed response time"?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't set `max_execution_time` less than the seocond. Also, `You can not change this setting with ini_set() when running in safe mode. The only workaround is to turn off safe mode or by changing the time limit in the php.ini.` 
[max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

But you can emulate it with a function as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869361/php-set-time-limit-less-than-one-second)

```
declare(ticks=1);
$start = microtime(1);
register_tick_function(function () use ($start) {
   (microtime(1) - $start < 0.8) or die();
});
```