# In mysql 5.6.21 is there any variable available just like max_statement_time?

Tags: mysql, database-administration

can I limit the maximum time allowed for a query to run in  mysql 5.6.21?

Comment: max_statement_time wasn't introduced until 5.7.4

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

time in `milliseconds`

```
SELECT MAX_STATEMENT_TIME = 1000 * FROM table;
```

or use this :-

```
SET GLOBAL MAX_STATEMENT_TIME=1000;
```

[More information](http://mysqlserverteam.com/server-side-select-statement-timeouts/)

if its not work please try this :-

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST
Run KILL [process id]
```

Comment: i am using  version 5.6.21 for mysql.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794747/mysql-can-i-limit-the-maximum-time-allowed-for-a-query-to-run

Comment: Please use `KILL QUERY [process id]`if you want to kill one particular query or it will kill all queries sharing this process id in the same session like a page request.