# MySQL concepts: session vs connection

Tags: mysql, database, session, connection, terminology

I'm a bit confused by MySQL concepts: session vs connection.

When talking about connecting to MySQL, we use connection terminology, connection pool, etc.

However in the MySQL online doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/server-system-variables.html, it talks about session variables.

They are quite similar. How to distinguish them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 43):

A `session` is just a result of a successful `connection`. Any MySQL client requires some connection settings to establish a connection and after the connection has been established it acquires a connection id (thread id) and some context which is called session.

Comment: if connection is idle too long, client try to reestablish it. a new session is initialized with a new set of session variables, right?

Comment: @xiaofeng-tang, correct, all user-defined variables will be NULLed, session variables will reset to defaults and temporary tables will be lost.

Answer (score 5):

**Connection** is ***the relationship*** between a client and a MySQL database.

**Session** is ***the period of time*** between a client logging in (connecting to) a MySQL database and the client logging out (exiting) the MySQL database.