# Change time execution limit

Tags: mysql

How do I change the limit in execution time for queries above 30'' ?

If I try

```
SET MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 3600
```

I receive

> error 1193 "unknown system variable MAX_EXECUTION_TIME"

I'm using MySQLWorkbench and mysql version 5.6.36

Answer (score 3):

If you are running MySQL 5.7.8 or later, you can use

```
SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 3600
```

to set it for the session, or

```
SET GLOBAL MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 3600
```

to set it globally. Note that this ability was first introduced in MySQL 5.7.4 as [max_statement_time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_statement_time); in 5.7.8 the name was changed to [max_execution_time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time).

Comment: Which version of MySQL do you have, this was only introduced in 5.7.8

Comment: I'm using MySQLWorkbench 8.0

Comment: Not the Workbench version, the MySQL server version

Comment: What do you get if you do `SELECT @@version`?

Comment: aargh, I see 5.6.36-log thank you for the suggestion. is there a work around for previous versions?

Answer (score 0):

If you have MySQL 5.7 or later, this parameter **MAX_EXECUTION_TIME** is for long running queries.

At first check the current value by running this query

```
> SELECT @@GLOBAL.MAX_EXECUTION_TIME @@SESSION.MAX_EXECUTION_TIME;
```

Then set it according to your needs.

```
> SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=3600;
> SET GLOBAL MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=3600;
```

Comment: I receive error 1193 12:12:05 SELECT @@GLOBAL.MAX_EXECUTION_TIME @@SESSION.MAX_EXECUTION_TIME Error Code: 1193. Unknown system variable 'MAX_EXECUTION_TIME' 0.0087 sec

Comment: look here, maybe you need to create a stored procedure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54005466/global-query-timeout-in-mysql-5-6 or to have a cron job https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794747/mysql-can-i-limit-the-maximum-time-allowed-for-a-query-to-run or you can do an upgrade to MySQL 5.7

Comment: It dosen't work in my case, error occurred while I run this with root user: [42000][1227] Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operatio

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting it at query level, like

```
SELECT +MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(3600) * FROM T
```

MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(N) applied to read only select statements.