# How set limit of execution time in select, but return the result in the end

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to set limit of execution in the select, but using the MAX_EXECUTION_TIME the query break and doesn't return the results. I need something like this code below. This is like the limit but with time execution. I need the query to stop running but return the result which was obtained.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%jean%'LIMIT 1 sec.
```

10 rows in 1 sec.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a maximum execution time for a mysql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415905/how-to-set-a-maximum-execution-time-for-a-mysql-query)

Comment: My question is different because I need the result when timeout.

Comment: Well, unfortunately you'll never get results after a timeout, by design. However, you make sure your queries don't hang forever which is always good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP try unbuffered queries and manage the timeout in PHP.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

Comment: Thank you, it's appear to be very useful I'll try use this and after give a feedback.

Answer (score -1):

There are two way,

1.Use **MAX_EXECUTION_TIME** hint in SQL as below.

```
mysql> select /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000) */ count(*) from tab1 a,tab1 b where a.cust_id = 3839203;
ERROR 3024 (HY000): Query execution was interrupted, maximum statement execution time exceeded
```

In the above SQL, there are no joins between both of table and having a huge amount of data. Hence it will take lots of time. But I have specified here to stop the query after running of 1000 ms or 1 sec.

2. You can set a session parameter that accepts in milliseconds before running to this query. And once you want to reset the value you can specify the different values for it.

## Before running your SQL

```
SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=1000;
```

## Post running your SQL

```
SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME= <<some different value or maximum value supported>>;
```

Comment: The MAX_EXECUTION_TIME is used to break the execution of the query, hence it won't gives any output if query didn't get processed within time. I don't think that there is any parameter like that which can give the processed output till execution terminates