# How can I set a system variable only if it exists?

Tags: mysql

I want to run this command when I start a MySQL session:

```
SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 1000
```

But I am running this on two different MySQL versions, and one of them doesn't support `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` so I get this error:

```
Unknown system variable 'MAX_EXECUTION_TIME'
```

I want to do something like

```
IF MAX_EXECUTION_TIME EXISTS THEN
SET SESSION MAX_EXECUTION_TIME = 1000
END IF
```

I have tried searching for things like "check if variable exists", "check if system variable exists", and "set system variable only if it exists" but I haven't found anything.

What is the right syntax for this?

Comment: Maybe you can try to SELECT the variable from system table? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23319195/188331)