# how to set mysql max_execution_time property use go

Tags: mysql, go

Im so sorry ask this but i have no useful msg after google.

dba prevent slow query affect mysql server， so we need control select statement execute time. I know variable `max_execution_time` affect that。 but i can not  find func in dtabase/sql.go ,  Who big man can give me some advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `SET max_execution_time=500` as a SQL statement. This limits the following SQL statements on the same connection to 0.5 seconds.

It is also possible as a SQL comment hint like `SELECT  /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000) */ field1, field2 FROM tbl ...` like
this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415905/how-to-set-a-maximum-execution-time-for-a-mysql-query#23319195).
If you show details about your slow query in a new question performance improvements may be possible.

Comment: The "on the same connection" caveat is important. As the go `sql` package uses connection pooling you cannot just `db.Exec("SET max_execution_time=500")` and the expect the next `db.Query` will use the same connection. An alternative is to use `context`.

Comment: Your hint made me enlightened, thank you