# Kill the SQL query processing if reaching timeout in MyBatis

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mybatis

i have a project using Springboot and MyBatis to write API like this

```
@Mapper
public interface ExportJobDetailRepository {
  List<RegularExportDetail> getExportJobDetailById(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper
    namespace="com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.dbaas.repository.ExportJobDetailRepository">

    <resultMap id="BaseResultMap"
        type="com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.dbaas.griddbdto.RegularExportDetail">
        <id column="id" property="id" />
        <result column="export_job_id" property="regularExportId" />
        <result column="containers" property="containers" />
        <result column="time_column" property="timeColumn" />
        <result column="row_filter" property="rowFilter" />
        <result column="export_method" property="exportMethod" />
    </resultMap>

    <select id="getExportJobDetailById" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
        SELECT * FROM
        export_job_detail
        where export_job_id = #{id}
        order by containers desc
    </select>
</mapper>
```

I need to write a function that can set timeout for API, and Kill the query processing if reach timeout. What should i do for this problem ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415905/how-to-set-a-maximum-execution-time-for-a-mysql-query) could be used

Comment: max_excution_query can only use for "select" query, is there any solution for other methods like delete, insert .. ?

Comment: @NghiHoàngĐức `<select|insert|update|delete>` has [`timeout`](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html) attribute which corresponds to [`java.sql.Statement#setQueryTimeout()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout(int)). Another important setting is [`java.sql.Connection#setNetworkTimeout()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#setNetworkTimeout(java.util.concurrent.Executor,int)) which can be set in JDBC connection URL or connection pool setting, usually.

Comment: @ave "timeout" attribute in MyBatis can only throw exception, I need to kill the process if it reaches time out, so which solution can kill the query process in MyBatis ?

Comment: @NghiHoàngĐức The [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) says `setQueryTimeout` internally issues `KILL QUERY`. If that is not what you want, please edit the question and elaborate on your requirement.